# How to utilize pandas string formatting

Tags: python, pandas

How can I explicitly access the excellent Series string formatting built-in to Pandas, to format my numbers like so:

```
>>> pd.Series([0.000034, 0.000035, 0.000038])
0    0.000034
1    0.000035
2    0.000038
dtype: float64
```

The `astype` only results in Python's plain float-to-string conversion:

```
>>> pd.Series([0.000034, 0.000035, 0.000038]).astype(str)
0    3.4e-05
1    3.5e-05
2    3.8e-05
dtype: object
```

(I realize I could parse the string generated by `pd.Series.__str__`, but looking for something less hackish.)

**Edit:** the reason I'd like to use the built-in Pandas formatting is that I don't know the range of the floats in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a sequence of floats, to get a Series of strings you could use:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.formats.format as pf
s = pd.Series(pf.FloatArrayFormatter([0.000034, 0.000035, 0.000038])
              .get_result_as_array())
print(s)
```

which prints

```
0     0.000034
1     0.000035
2     0.000038
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

Use format

```
In [1149]: pd.Series([0.000034, 0.000035, 0.000038]).apply('{:.6f}'.format)
Out[1149]:
0    0.000034
1    0.000035
2    0.000038
dtype: object
```

Comment: See my edit; there you have the reason I'd like to use Pandas built-in formatting and not hard-code it.